# Thermal expansion timescale for solids

Tags: thermodynamics

In some works related to Nuclear Reactor engineering, I saw the estimates for the thermal expansion time of the solid phase (without any explanation). I am curious, how can you estimate the expansion time. Suppose, the temperature of the solid body increases instantaneously by, say, 100 Celsius (that can happen if the reactor is prompt supercritical). Let's say, that after that temperature is fixed (some safety system terminated nuclear reaction). How to estimate the thermal expansion time of the solid body (of course, it's material type and geometry is known)? I am not interested in a precise answer, just rough estimate (e.g. order of milliseconds). What characteristics determine the rate of the thermal expansion?

Any links will be useful. After a quick search, I didn't find any theory on this topic. Basic theory describes the coefficient of thermal expansion, but I am interested in dynamics.

My guess would be characteristic length (of the solid body) / speed of sound.

Thanks

Comment: I think your guess is good $c=\sqrt {B/\rho}$

Comment: Thermal expansion occurs due to more vigorous molecular motion, but more vigorous molecular motion is simultaneously also a measure of increased temperature. My point is, if you say the body has reached a uniform temperature of 100 deg C, then the body has already expanded uniformly everywhere. Perhaps the data that you saw was for the time required for the entire body to reach a particular higher temperature once the ambient temperature is suddenly changed. In that case the required time scale is $L^2/\alpha$, where $L$ is length and $\alpha$ is thermal diffusivity of the body.